# How to find exactly "\n" in Python IDLE replace dialog?

Tags: python, regex, replace, line-breaks

I'm a begginer in Python and one of the first codes I've made it's an RPG, so there's a lot of texts in strings being printed. Before I learned how to "word wrap", I used to test every string and put an "\n" in the right places, so it could be better to read the history in the console.

But now I don't need those "\n" anymore, and it's been really laborious to replace each one of them using the Replace Dialog of Python IDLE. One of the problems is that I want to ignore double new lines ("\n\n"), because they do make the texts more presentable.

So if I just search "\n" he finds it, but I want to ignore all the "\n\n".

I tried using the "Regular expression" option and did a research with regex but with no success, since I'm completly new in this area. Tried some things like **"^\n$"** because, if I understood it right, the ^ and the $ delimit the search to what's between them.

I think it's clear what I need, but will write an example anyways:

```
print("Here's the narrator telling some things to the player. Of course I could do some things but\nnow it's time to ask for help!\n\nProbably it's a simple thing, but it's been lots of time in research and no\nsuccess...")
```

I want to find and replace those two "\n" with one empty space (" ") and totally ignore the "\n\n".

Can you guys help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with a brief explanation of lookbehind/lookahead expressions that would make a perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xv7m7o/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\n)` - no newline allowed immediately on the left
- `\n` - a newline
- `(?!\n)` - no newline allowed immediately on the right

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/W8XowI):

```
import re
text = "Here's the narrator telling some things to the player. Of course I could do some things but\nnow it's time to ask for help!\n\nProbably it's a simple thing, but it's been lots of time in research and no\nsuccess..."
print(re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)', ' ', text))
```

Output:

```
Here's the narrator telling some things to the player. Of course I could do some things but now it's time to ask for help!

Probably it's a simple thing, but it's been lots of time in research and no success...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm trying to rewrite the code in IDLE using the Replace Dialog. I tried to put "r'(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)'" and "(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)" in the Find Box but none of them could find the single break line. I need to rewrite the code because in some times I have to maintain certain single break line (i.e. if the narrator show's a list of options to the player). In your answer, I think I would need to put the regex in a new definition of print() or something, which is not wanted. I need a regex to use in the Replace Dialog which will find the single "\n". Is it possible?

Comment: @BrunoBauer Use in the text editor, like Notepad++, VSCode, SublimeText.

Comment: I've got it!! "(?<!\\n)\\n(?!\\n)", just put another "\" in the "\n" and it worked! Thanks!